# How to extract image from ms Access to file directory

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, vba

I have gone through a data migration and previous data is stored in MS-Access DB so the database has file attachment field,, here is the problem that i want to extract attached file or image to file directory. 
OR if its possible for conversion to MySQL database.
Any Solution ???

Comment: Review https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835669.aspx. When you develop code that has specific issue, post question.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I've tried workbench, Ms-Access Image extractor, and some of tools are not supporting accdb extension also i cannot convert it to mdb because its new features like macros ...etc.